# extjs 4 error when attempting to use view

Tags: extjs, view, namespaces, controller, extjs4

Using extjs 4 I get an error when attempting to use a view in my viewport. I think it is an issue with how the view is defined/where it is included. However, I can';t find what I've done wrong. I know this is an easy mistake, I just don't see it. I'll post the code below. Error is

TypeError: name is undefined

View I want to use:

```
Ext.define('MC.view.SideBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.SideBar',
    items:[
        { xtype: 'panel',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        html:'facebook'
        },
        { xtype: 'panel',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        html:'twitter?'
        }

    ]
    //... more configuration ...
});
```

Viewport

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: {
        //align:'center',
        pack:'center',
        type:'hbox',
        align:'stretch',
        border:true
    },
    items: [
        {xtype:'panel',
            layout:{
            type:'vbox',
            align:'stretch',
            pack:'start'
            },
            border:true,
            width: '80%',
            items:[
                {xtype:'panel',
                    border:true,
                    flex:2,
                    //width:'100%',
                    html:'toolbar/logo'
                },
                {xtype:'panel',
                    border:true,
                    flex:8,

                    layout:{
                        type:'hbox',
                        align:'stretch',
                        pack:'start'
                    },
                    items: [
                        //{xtype:'SideBar'},
                        **{xtype:'SideBar',**
                            flex:22,
                            height:'100%'
                        },
                        {xtype:'panel',
                            flex:88,
                            height:'100%'
                        }
                    ],

                    html:'lower'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

Controller where views are referenced

```
Ext.define('MC.controller.Monolith', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: [
        'TopBar', 'SideBar'
    ],

    init: function() {
        console.log('Initialized Monolith controller! This happens before the Application launch function is called');
    }
});
```

Finally the application file

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MC',
    //appFolder: 'app', 
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    controllers: [
        'Monolith'
    ],
    //models: [],
    //stores: [],
    launch: function() {
        console.log('mesacart');

        // This is fired as soon as the page is ready
    }
});
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but it must be simple since there isnt much code here yet....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For views and controllers you **don't** need to specify their 'MC.controller' and 'MC.view' prefix when declaring them.

So you end up with:

```
views: [
        'TopBar', 'SideBar'
    ],
```

and so on.

EDIT:
when you ask to auto create the viewport you need to define a viewport class as MC.view.Viewport 
See your full code example in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/qW4hR/

```
Ext.define('MC.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: {...}
```

Comment: SO did you mean to say "you don't need to specify their 'MC.controller' and 'MC.view' prefix when declaring them." or did you mean to say "you don't HAVE to specify their 'MC.controller' and 'MC.view' prefix when declaring them."  Because I took the prefix out and my issue persists.

Comment: Take a look at this code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/8f8EC/ notice how Controllers and Views are defined with full namespace and how they are referenced by just their Name.

Comment: Right, I've got that. I changed that. I'll reflect it in my code above. But, the problem persists.

Comment: I'll try that but the viewport works fine when i use s panel in place of my custom ctype

Comment: That did it! That is odd though, considering the viewport rendered when using built-in xtypes....

Comment: Well you did both: ask for an auto created viewport AND used Ext.create to create a viewport. use one or the other.